# Magento Promotions -> Conditions Attributes empty

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules, promotions

I am looking after a Magento installation running 1.9.2.2. Under `Promotions > Catalogue Price Rule conditions` there is no `pre-filled conditions` such as `SKU`. How do I fix this? I am following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H83fFszyhrU

What it is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `sku` attribute is not enabled for `promo rule conditions`. To use it for promo rules, go to `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes`, click on the `sku` attribute, and set Use for `Promo Rule Conditions` to `Yes`. Save it, and you should be able to use it for promo rules now.

[image]